# Terminology and approximation to logarithm of a sum of products of binomial coefficients

Tags: co.combinatorics, asymptotics, approximation-theory, binomial-coefficients, entropy

Denote $$T(m)=\sum_{1\leq n_m\leq n_{m-1}\leq\dots\leq n_2\leq n_1\leq m}\prod_{i=1}^{m}\binom{n_i}{n_{i+1}}.$$

Is there a name for this kind of summation and is there a good estimate for $\ln T(m)$ bounded above and below by constant factors (preferably additively)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that the product of binomial coefficients can be expressed as a [multinomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem):
$$\prod_{i=1}^m \binom{n_i}{n_{i+1}} = \binom{n_1}{n_1-n_2,n_2-n_3,\dots,n_{m-1}-n_m,n_m}.$$
Denoting $d_i:=n_i-n_{i+1}$ for $i<m$ and $d_m:=n_m$, and noticing that they all are non-negative except $d_m$ which is positive, we get
$$T(m) = \sum_{d_1+d_2+\dots+d_m\leq m} \binom{d_1+d_2+\dots+d_m}{d_1,d_2,\dots,d_m} - \sum_{d_1+d_2+\dots+d_{m-1}\leq m} \binom{d_1+d_2+\dots+d_{m-1}}{d_1,d_2,\dots,d_{m-1}},$$
where the sums are taken over non-negative indices.

Now,
\begin{split}
\sum_{d_1+d_2+\dots+d_m\leq D} \binom{d_1+d_2+\dots+d_m}{d_1,d_2,\dots,d_m}
&= \sum_{s=0}^D \sum_{d_1+d_2+\dots+d_m=s} \binom{s}{d_1,d_2,\dots,d_m}\\
&= \sum_{s=0}^D m^s \\
&= \frac{m^{D+1}-1}{m-1}.
\end{split}

Therefore,
$$T(m) = \frac{m^{m+1}-1}{m-1} - \frac{(m-1)^{m+1}-1}{m-2}.$$